# Install dlib(from source, gpu) on Jetson NX did not work correctly

Tags: gpu, dlib, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to use dlib (GPU) on Jetson Xavier NX, following are my steps to install dlib-19.19

```
dowload dlib repo from repo: https://github.com/davisking/dlib
cd dlib-19.19
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1
```

got the message

```
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found suitable version "10.2", minimum required is "7.5") 
-- Looking for cuDNN install...
-- Found cuDNN: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so
-- Building a CUDA test project to see if your compiler is compatible with CUDA...
-- Checking if you have the right version of cuDNN installed.
-- *** Found cuDNN, but it looks like the wrong version so dlib will not use it.              ***
-- *** Dlib requires cuDNN V5.0 OR GREATER.  Since cuDNN is not found DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA. ***
-- *** If you have cuDNN then set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to include cuDNN's folder.                ***
-- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
```

Any ideas on this issue? How to install dlib (GPU) from source on Jetson correctly?

Answer (score 0):

My environment: Xavier NX + JetPack 4.6

I solved this issue following the help here:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/simple-accelerated-face-recognition/142679/19

**Most importantly, make sure you use dlib19.21, neither dlib19.23 nor dlib 19.17.**